# Gradle 4.x API instead of implementation - How can i use gradle API feature to expose internal dependencies

Tags: gradle

I'm using gradle 4.x and here is my problem.

I've two modules A and B.

Module B has project dependency on module A. Here are the gradle files.

build.gradle for module A

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka' , version: '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-spring-service-connector'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector'

    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation group: 'io.github.benas', name: 'random-beans', version: '3.7.0'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

Here is the build.gradle for module B

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':moduleA')

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka' , version: '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-spring-service-connector'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector'

    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation group: 'io.github.benas', name: 'random-beans', version: '3.7.0' }

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

If you observe the build.gradle file for module B, i've a dependency for spring-kafka but it's a duplicate since it's already in module A build.gradle.
Now how can use gradle API option to expose spring-kafka (from module A) without actually mentioning it in module B's build.gradle when the jar file of module B is being consumed by another app?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the docs [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) (emphasis mine):

> The plugin exposes two [configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_dependency_configurations.html#managing_dependency_configurations) that can be used to declare dependencies: `api` and `implementation`. **The `api` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are exported by the library API**, whereas the `implementation` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the component.

So simply change `implementation` to `api` in `moduleA`:

```
api group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka' , version: '2.2.7.RELEASE'
```

Then remove the entry from `moduleB`'s Gradle file.